# Which verb should be used with the nouns "repair/maintenance": "Make"/"Do"/"Carry out"/...?

Tags: word-choice, technical

The following sentence is used on a warning label:

> All maintenance and repair must be done only by authorized personnel

I'm not quite sure that "do" is the proper verb to use with "maintenance and repair". Which verb would fit better with these nouns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Carried out* is indeed a good one. To me, any of these would fit well in this case:

> - Carried out
> - Conducted
> - Performed
> - (executed?)
> - (handled?)